# SQL Query Optimization with SUM(case when)

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns: name and money, 'money' has positive as well as negative values.
I have written a sql query to get the sum of the total money withdrew and deposited. I was wondering if there was any way to make this query more efficient and work faster.

```
select name,
       SUM(case when money > 0 then money else 0 end) as deposit,
       ABS(SUM(case when money < 0 then money else 0 end)) as withdraw
from transfer
group by name
order by name ;
```

Comment: As there are no `WHERE` or `HAVING` restrictions, your query cannot really benefit from any index.  It is already optimal.

Comment: The big hit to performance is generally reads – as @TimBiegeleisen states, with no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses you can't do much. Joins are the other big factor on efficiency, which you have none of assuming your sample is representative of your system

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: *FYI:* In your query, both the `deposit` and the `withdraw` result column are summing up positive values. I believe `withdraw` is supposed to use `money < 0` as the condition, otherwise `ABS()` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually believe adding index over `name` might improve your plan quite a bit: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/indexing-for-group-by/

As other answers and comments suggest it's sort of expected that you'd have some form of identity in the table that you would build clustered index upon, but for your particular query I'd say you could try indexing over name and including `money` so there's less reads required

To really tell what's going on you might need to check query plans with and without indexes and see if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Since your query doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, it has to read the *entire* table. That's your primary performance issue.

It then has to group all that the data. That's your secondary performance issue.

There is nothing that can be done to improve either, except maybe clustering the table by `name`, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Note that there _are_ certainly ways to improve `GROUP BY` queries, if, for example, the aggregate being requested is something like min or max.  But `SUM` is not too index friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Most database engines would make use of a covering index for this query.  That would be an index on `(name, money)`.

The result query plan is essentially a scan of the index.  This handles the `group by` because all rows with the same `name` are adjacent.  The `money` column is already in the index, so it does not need to be looked up on the data pages.

That said, not all databases implement this optimization.  Even those that don't might still use the covering index, which would reduce the I/O for the query.